# Inequality Constrained Least Squares Problem - Trust Region Sub Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, least-squares

Given the following dual optimization problem:

$$\min_x \|Ax - y\|_2\quad\text{such that}\quad \|x\|_2 \leq r.$$

What is the minimizer?

Given the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $A^+,$ it is evident to me that if $\|A^+ y\| \leq r$, then $A^+ y$ is the minimizer to that problem. But what if $\|A^+ y\| > r?$ Is calculating $r {A^+ y \over \|A^+ y\|}$ enough?

Comment: The problem can be rewritten as a QCQP.

Comment: Either the solution you provided is optimal, or the constraint $\Vert x \Vert_2 \leq r$ holds with equality. In the later case, the problem is equivalent to minimizing $\Vert Ax-y\Vert_2^2$ s.t. $\Vert x \Vert_2^2=r^2$. By taking the KKT conditions of this problem's Lagrangian you should be able to show that $x^\star=(A^\top A+\lambda \mathbb{I})^{-1} A^\top y$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier), and use the condition $x^\top x=r^2$ to solve for $\lambda$. So you can certainly parameterize the optimal $x$ in terms of $\lambda$ and find $\lambda$ via binary search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs in trust-region algorithms for optimization and is known as the "trust-region subproblem" (sometimes "trust region subproblem.")  There are many papers written about efficient and accurate numerical methods for its solution.  There's no simple closed form solution.